# Number of subsets with no pairwise intersection of cardinality 2?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Consider $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of $[n]$ , each subset having cardinality $k$, such that

$\forall x,y \in \mathcal{F}, |x \cap y | \not = \frac{k}{2}.$

Is there any known result or technique to find a (non-trivial) upper bound on the maximal cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$?

The actual problem I care about is in fact more specific, with $k=4$. Then the question becomes: What is an upper bound on the number of 4-subsets of $[n]$ such that no two subsets have an intersection of cardinality 2?

Comment: One route might be to compute these values by hand for several small $n$, and see if it’s a sequence which is already known in the OEIS.

Comment: There is a large literature on "forbidden intersection problems". Try googling "eventown and oddtown" for a friendly introduction. There is a theorem of Frankl and Wilson that implies that your family of $4$-subsets has cardinality at most $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3}$, but maybe there is a stronger bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate the problem as finding a maximum independent set in a graph $G=(N,E)$ with one node per $k$-subset and an edge for each pair of $k$-subsets that intersect in exactly $k/2$ elements.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is part of the independent set.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i\in N} x_i$ subject to linear constraints $x_i + x_j \le 1$ for all edges $(i,j)\in E$.  Summing these constraints yields
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in E} (x_i+x_j) \le |E|.\tag1\label1$$
Because the graph is regular of degree
$\Delta = 2|E|/|N|$,
\eqref{1} reduces to
$$\Delta \sum_{i\in N} x_i \le |E|,$$
yielding upper bound
$$\sum_{i\in N} x_i \le \frac{|E|}{\Delta} = \frac{|N|}{2}.$$

For $n\in\{1,\dots,15\}$, the actual maximum values $a_{n,4}$ are much smaller:
$$0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 11, 12, 18, 20, 22, 29, 32.$$

By considering subsets that do not contain a particular element, we obtain the recurrence relation
$$a_{n,k} \le \frac{n}{n-k} a_{n-1,k}.$$

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer. Where do you get this upper bound of the maximum independent set from? It doesn't seem to comply with the usual (tight) bound.

Comment: @StefanS I have now corrected the upper bound, which applies to any regular graph.

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt. The asymptotic scaling of the bound you provide is O(n^4), so worse than the Frankl Wilson bound of O(n^3). I'm not marking this as solved yet because I'm wondering whether one can prove a much tighter bound, in agreement with the much smaller numerical values you computed.